# How long* cast works

Tags: c++, pointers

So I have this chunk of code

```
char buf[2];
buf[0] = 'a';
buf[1] = 'b';

std::cout << *((long *)((void*)buf) + 1) << std::endl;
```

When I saw that I said to myself:

We have memory address 1000 (for example) and that's the address of buf[1].
So I thought that *((long *)((void*)buf) + 1) will print out whatever is in addresses:
from 1000 until 1000 + sizeof(long)

But that's not the case. This code prints **always** -858993460

What is that number and why it isn't random?

I obviously lack the knowledge to understand what is going on so I would appreciate if you could give me a hint or something!

Comment: If `buf` is of size 2, I don't see why you would want to read past its end. What did you expect to find there? Not to mention that this is also platform specific due to endianness. If will also cause a trap on some systems where you cannot read `long`s or even `int`s on odd addresses. Where is `buf` declared, stack or heap?

Comment: @Groo It's just a test I made but as I said I had unexpected results. 
buf is declared on stack. I will edit post to make it more clear

Comment: Interesting, at least for me it always prints out `0`...

Comment: I would expect unexpected results in this case. :) For example, running it in release mode or with different optimizations enabled would easily return something else or, more likely, crash.

Comment: this number, in hex notation 0xFFFFFFFFCCCCCCCC - value used by some compilers to indicate not initialized memory

Comment: @Lashane -- just curious, do you know off hand which compilers do this and which ones don't?

Comment: @mattingly890 at least msvc should do this

Comment: @Groo Yeah that's my problem. It always prints the same number.

Comment: @Lashane Really? Ok that's a usefull information! I guess Visual Studio compiler does that too!

Comment: @TheCrafter microsoft visual studio uses.... microsoft visual c (msvc) compiler

Comment: @TheCrafter: yes, you can use the Memory window in VS to see the contents of memory around that address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is that number and why it isn't random?

It is a random value. Nothing in your program suggests that value should be printed.

It happens to be consistent so far as you've run your program. Maybe you haven't run it enough. Using uninitialized memory produces undefined behavior. Programs with UB might work as intended for years and then fail to compile.

By the way, your expression doesn't have the intended meaning. Try adding more spaces.

```
* ( (long *) ((void*)buf) + 1 )
```

First you cast `buf` to `void *`, then you cast it againt to `long *`, then you added one (to get the next `long`, not the next byte), and then fetched a `long` from memory. The bytes that got printed are entirely outside the `char[2]` array.

Comment: So as expected it is totally undefined what there is in the part of memory there. I think I got it now! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This code is reading past the end of a buffer and so is a security risk and completely undefined behaviour.

The contents of memory beyond `buf` could be *anything*.

Your compiler, architecture, and/or build settings may be such that currently that value is the same each time you run it, but that's just blind chance and could change at any point.

It will be different again on 64-bit systems where `long` is 64 bits wide. Alignment rules may also cause this code to fail outright.

Summary: even though this code is returning you the same result for each run right now, this is totally unsafe and undefined behaviour.

Avoid.

Comment: Yeah I know I should avoid it. It was just a test. The surprise for me is that it **always** prints the same value. That's odd!!

Comment: Not all that odd, undefined behaviour doesn't mean it will be different every time, in fact it may often be the same when run under an identical build/execution environment. Try running an optimised or instrumented build and the output may well change.

Comment: Or it may crash! (If your tools can detect bugs like this at runtime).

Answer (score 1):

At a particular instant the value in a particular memory address will be constant unless other variables are created which take it's place. In your program if you output the memory address of `buf` it will be the same. Which means that you would be referring to the same address everytime the program is run and hence the same garbage value would be printed.

Comment: It depends. With invalid addresses, it's hard to tell what they are pointing to.

Comment: the address of buf is fixed and if you add anything constant to that it would also be fixed.... so the long pointer is pointing to a fixed address with a random garbage value